# Рекурсивное заполнение сущностей symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3, php7

```
class User {

  private $name;
  private $group;

  public function getName() : string
  {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function getGroup() : Group
  {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function setName(string $name) :void
  {
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function setGroup($group) :void
  {
    $this->group = new Group($group);
  }
}
```

Допустим есть некая сущность User, и я хочу автоматически рекурсивно её заполнять так, чтобы автоматом заполнились и внутренние обьекты. Есть ли в Symfony готовое решения для этого?

Comment: Что понимается под рекурсивным заполнением?

Comment: @mxSandr вставка массива/объекта в конструктор объекта, который хотим заполнить, срабатывают set/add в объекте и заполняются на основе имени свойства и наличия у него set/add, и так по всей структуре объекта и наличию идентичной вложенности. Для этого я написал trait, но есть подозрения, что изобрел колесо.

Comment: Если подразумевается какая-то нетривиальная логика инстанцирования объекта, лучше реализуйте шаблон "Фабричный метод". В симфони описываемого вами функционала нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю вам стоит воспользоваться компонентом Сериализации(Serializing). Данные компонент позволяет переводить данные в объект и наоборот из разных форматов. 
[Ссылка на документацию.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)